# anyone using IXCLRDataProcess, GetRuntimeNameByAddress and ICLRDataTarget to get managed symbol?

Tags: debugging, windbg

the purpose is to get a mixed callstack. For managed symbol, I use `IXCLRDATAProcess / GetRuntimeNameByAddress` to resolve the corresponding managed callstack. I modify this [project](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/371137/a-mixed-mode-stackwalk-with-the-idebugclient-inter) to get self-mixed callstack, it works on X86, but it failed on X64. after debugging, I find the issue is located in `IXCLRDATAProcess`. Our project is located in [this](https://github.com/MingbaiLiu/IdebugClient).

this is my way to use `IXCLRDATAProcess`：

```
HANDLE processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, ProcessId);
void** iface;
BOOL isWow64 = FALSE;

if (processHandle == NULL)
    return NULL;

BOOLEAN result = IsWow64Process(processHandle, &isWow64);
DiagCLRDataTarget* dataTarget = new DiagCLRDataTarget(ProcessId, processHandle, isWow64, debugNative); //new DnCLRDataTarget;
ICLRDataTarget* target = static_cast<ICLRDataTarget*>(dataTarget);

HMODULE accessDll = LoadLibraryW(L"C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework64\\v4.0.30319\\mscordacwks.dll");
PFN_CLRDataCreateInstance entry = (PFN_CLRDataCreateInstance)GetProcAddress(accessDll, "CLRDataCreateInstance");

hr = entry(__uuidof(IXCLRDataProcess), target, (void**)&ifacePtr); // error
if (FAILED(hr)) {
    std::cout << "error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl; // where we get error: 203:230 (0xE6) The pipe state is invalid.
    *iface = ifacePtr;
}
m_clrDataProcess = static_cast<IXCLRDataProcess*>(iface);
```

then I use `m_clrDataProcess` to resolve the symbol, that is

```
    hr = m_clrDataProcess->GetRuntimeNameByAddress(clrAddr, 0, maxSize - 1, &nameLen, buffer, &displacement);
```

due to the `m_clrDataProcess` being null, we can't resolve symbol from the frame address. Does anyone use these API or does anyone have some advice?

Comment: Looking at your code, I would guess that something is wrong with `DiagCLRDataTarget`. And quoting the project you took it from: `I cut some corners doing the implementation. I only support the x86 architecture.`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. you are right. now I have modified my code, it has a param named `machineType` that needs to configure, and now everything is fine.